# Writing logs to log file as well as kafka

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, logback, distributed-system

I currently have microservice environment and each service write logs to it's own file.
I want to achieve distributed logging and for that I found a solution using elk . But I do not want to disturb my current architecture of writing  logs to multiple files.

Is it possible that I can write logs to file and then send the same to kafka topic.

PS. I am currently using log back for logging.

Comment: what's elk??? kibana?

Comment: @KaidulIslam ELK = Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana. Kibana is a GUI analytics tool for data in Elasticsearch.

Comment: Why don't you use Filebeat in the container to ship logs to Elastic and Kafka?

Answer (score 2):

you just have to add an appender on your existing configuration, you don't really need to "disturb" your architecture.

[Here](https://github.com/danielwegener/logback-kafka-appender) a logback kafka appender, you can simply add to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.danielwegener</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-kafka-appender</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- probably you already have the following or the ones provided by spring, this is an example -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
    <version>4.8</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

and in your `src/main/resources/logback.xml` you can add the appender and use it:

```
<appender name="kafkaAppender" class="com.github.danielwegener.logback.kafka.KafkaAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <topic>logs</topic>
        <keyingStrategy class="com.github.danielwegener.logback.kafka.keying.NoKeyKeyingStrategy" />
        <deliveryStrategy class="com.github.danielwegener.logback.kafka.delivery.AsynchronousDeliveryStrategy" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </appender>

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="kafkaAppender" />
</root>
```

Other appenders are available if you check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

A more standard pattern would be simply to send events from your microservice directly to Kafka. From there you can stream it to Elasticsearch and any number of other targets. Writing to log to then read from log is completely redundant.